# Re-run the execution if API call fails in R

Tags: r, api, loops, error-handling, automation

I have the following API call function:

```
 df.load <- loaddf(r = as.character(readline(prompt = "Please enter r parameter: "))
                                  ,y= as.character(readline(prompt = "Please enter y parameter: "))
                                  ,z= as.character(readline(prompt = "Please enter z parameter: ")) )
                                  ,format="json"
    
    

# Convert to dataframe
data.df <- as.data.frame(df.load )
```

However, sometimes it fails to connect:

```
Warning in file(file, "rt") :
  InternetOpenUrl failed: 'A connection with the server could not be established'
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
```

and a number of observations in the final dataframe `data.df` is equal to 0, but when I re-run the code 3-4 times, it works.

Therefore I want to push R to re-run this chunk in the .rmd file if the connection failed or a number of observations are equal to 0 in `data.df`.
Or if you have any other ideas on how to solve this issue I am open to your suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: Check `?tryCatch` or `?withRestarts`. Also please see [this related chapter](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/beyond-exception-handling.html) from *Advanced R*. For future readers searching for REST API calls please see this blog post on [httr::RETRY](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2020/04/retries-in-api-packages-and-reinventing-the-wheel/).

Comment: It looks really attractive solution thanks! However, I have some difficulties implementing it into my code. New question is posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71854077/implement-call-retries-with-retry-function-in-api-call-r